# should i use ubuntu or centos 7 for magento 2 development

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have worked on windows and it is very very slow with so many errors , i need a recommendation what linux should i use for development in magento 2 .
Centos 7 , Ubuntu or anything else i want supper fast speed . (local computer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using Ubuntu (without docker, vagrant, etc.) for Magento development during the last 4 years - and it was pretty fast.

I've run all types of tests - unit, integration, API-functional, MTF, and MFTF (which are "slow" by their nature) on my local machine. Even, I had multiple running instances at the same time.

Now, I'm using macOS for the development, it a little bit slower when on Ubuntu but much faster when on Windows.

Few tips, which were helped me to achieve the most performance:

- Use `bin/magento setup:di:compile` - to generate all auto-generated code
- `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` - to generate all js and CSS files
- Disable `Xdebug` for CLI - allows speeding up tests execution, if you need debugging for tests, such IDE as PHPStorm allows enabling it in runtime

UPD: some time ago I did some benchmarks for tests execution. Running one set of `150` integrations tests take: `38sec` on Linux machine, `1min 45sec` on Windows machine (the instance was on Virtualbox with Ubuntu and with codebase on Windows) - Windows native much slower.

Comment: I am planning to add ubuntu along with windows 10 what do you think is that ok ?

Comment: @MagentoBug, I'm not Windows user for many years, just using from time to time for different benchmarks. But I don't prefer using different OSx on the same machine. My favorite is Linux Mint.

Comment: 2019 - people still do not understand where the “speed” comes from... the application doesn't care where you run it... linux, windows, or even your casio calculator... it only needs CPU power, SSD storage and proper php code, in case of magento 2 development it also needs simplicity, do not overload it with cumbersome features your customers never use. everything else is up to you, if you know how to manage web stack - just run it

Comment: @MagenX, I partially agree with you but OS also important because infrastructure like apache, docker, mysql, php, whatever anyway use it. On the same laptop configuration Magento much faster on Linux than on Windows.